# Postfix: Set custom SMTP Banner based on domain (same ip) used to access server

Tags: postfix, smtp, banner

I have multiple domains on my server pointing to the same ip address.

How can I setup postfix to greet with each individual smtp banner based on the domain name?
I've searched everywhere but didn't find a good solution, maybe it isn't possible at all?!

for exmpl.:

```
ServerIP - Domain - SMTP Banner should look like this
93.184.216.34 - domain1.com - "220 domain1.com ESMTP Postfix"
93.184.216.34 - domain2.net - "220 domain2.net ESMTP Postfix"
93.184.216.34 - domain3.org - "220 domain3.org ESMTP Postfix"
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible.  SMTP is not a hostname-aware service; unlike (eg) HTTP, the server is never told what domain name the client looked up to discover the server's IP address, so it has no way of knowing which domain name the client expects to see reflected back at it.